# parentheses inside for loop initialization

Tags: c++, syntax, for-loop, initialization, parentheses

```
for (int i(0); i < 10; ++i) { ... }
```

Has the `int i(0)` syntax inside the for loop initializer always been allowed in standard C++?

It compiles fine with `g++ -std=c++98`, but I don't trust compilers when it comes to standard details.

Comment: I never thought about it, since I use `int i = 0;` for my initialization needs, but I don't see the problem with it. It's just an alternate form of initializing the variable, so I would presume it's just fine being where an initialization is allowed.

Comment: for (int i(0),  without the =, works fine in MSVC++ too.

Comment: does it make any temporary object or something?

Comment: no problem in VC++ 2010 express

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the relevant parts of the syntax found in *The C++ Programming Language*, Appendix A:

```
iteration-statement:
    ...
    for (for-init-statement condition_opt; expression_opt) statement

for-init-statement:
    ...
    simple-declaration

simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seq_opt init-declarator-list_opt;

init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
    declarator initializer_opt

initializer:
    = initializer_clause
    ( expression-list )
```

So yes, the `for (int i(0); ...` syntax has always been allowed in standard C++.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It's a simple variable declaration (a *simple-declaration* in language grammar) which was explicitly allowed in C++ for loop's *for-init-statement* (as opposed to C back then).

Especially, in the language grammar the following are equivalent (both are *simple-declarations*):

```
int i(0);
int i = 0;
```